# The syntax for smart pointer

Tags: c++

In this declration for a unique pointer

```
  std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, void(*)(SDL_Window*)> window_;
```

I could not find any resource with this kind of decration so my guess is that we create a pointer and pass it to the function and the return value is stored in window_

Comment: I prefer to create dedicated functor for deleter, simpler to use (and allows EBO).

Comment: Hi, what is your *question*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is just declaring the variable `window_`, it doesn't initialize it at all.

The resource you're looking for is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
template<
  class T,
  class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>
  > class unique_ptr;
```

It's just declaring a unique ptr with a non-default deleter: the `void(*)(SDL_Window*)` part is the type of a function pointer, which means the correct deleter function must be passed in when you initialize `window_`.

If only one deleter function is really used, it's nicer to make it a functor, where the function is a static method of the functor type and doesn't need to be passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not find any resource with this kind of decration

This is a variable declaration. Type of the variable is `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, void(*)(SDL_Window*)>` and name of the variable is `window_`. More specifically, the variable is default initialised, which in case of non-trivial types such as `std::unique_ptr` means that the default constructor will be called. The default constructor of `std::unique_ptr` initialises itself as null pointer.